# Как передать в хранимую процедуру mssql, которая принимает xml, переменную тип XElement из C#

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server

У меня есть переменная authorsXml типа XElement, вида:

```
<Author name="Name" surname="Surname" />
<Author name="Name2" surname="Surname2" />
```

как мне эту переменную передать в хранимую процедуру, которая принимает xml?
Код C#:

```
 IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand(); 

 IDbDataParameter temp = command.CreateParameter();
 temp.ParameterName = "@Authors";
 temp.Value = authorsXml;

command.Parameters.Add(temp);
```

В value что именно нужно передавать? что бы записались обе node

Comment: я передавал просто строку и все корректно записывалось, в вашем случае `authorsXml.ToString()`

Comment: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Authors", SqlDbType.Xml, authorsXml);